# why assigning an object literal to a variable with type makes error?

Tags: typescript

```
type MyType = { name: string };

const mytype = {
  name: 'kim',
  age: 10
};

const my: MyType = mytype; // no error
```

```
type MyType = { name: string };

const my: MyType = {
  name: 'kim',
  age: 10 // error
};
```

I do not understand why assigning the object literal to the variable `my` with the type `MyType` makes an error.